# python populate file passing variables to jinja

Tags: python-2.7, jinja2

I am playing around with jinja to populate a file for various apps I have. This is the file. For every app I should get a similar block.

```
{
    {{ app }}: {
        "nat1": {{ nat1 }},
        "nat2": {{ nat2 }},
        "rt": {{ rt }}
    }
}
```

This is python code I am using to render template.

```
def render_template(a, b, c, d):
    loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader( searchpath='/')
    template_env = jinja2.Environment( loader = loader)
    template_file = "/home/ubuntu/check.json"
    template = template_env.get_template(template_file)
    template_vars = {
        "app": a,
        "nat1": b,
        "nat2": c,
        "rt": d
    }
    output = template.render(template_vars)
    with open("/home/ubuntu/check.json", "w") as fh:
        fh.write(output)
```

I call render_template for every app I have.
Issue is that I am unable to generate block for each app, the output in template file is always one of the apps. Can some one please help me get all my apps in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how I would do it: I would use json builtin module after some functions/variables renamming

```
import json
def save_check(app, nat1, nat2, rt):
    check_dict = {
        app: {
            "nat1": nat1,
            "nat2": nat2,
            "rt": rt
        }
    }
    with open("/home/ubuntu/check.json", "w") as fh:
        json.dump(check_dict, fh, indent=4)
```